# VirtualHost doesn't work

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache2, virtualhost

I have a very simple configuration but I only receive a "page not avaiable" as response.

Currently I'm running an Amazon EC2 instance with EBS and RDD and using Route53 as the DNS system. The DNS are correctly working and pointing to the EC2 machine (checked with a nslookup)

In the EC2 machine I created my site in the folder:

```
/var/www/html/pazzanicastanhas.com.br
```

and in the file /etc/httpd/conf.d/httpd-vhosts.conf I have only the following

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/pazzanicastanhas.com.br
  ServerName www.pazzanicastanhas.com.br
</VirtualHost>
```

When I try to access the site through the domain www.pazzanicastanhas.com.br I just get a error saying the page doesn't exist, if I use the default public DNS or the direct IP of the machine provided by amazon, everything works. **The thing is the virtualhost doesn't understand to point the domain to the correct folder in the machine.**

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

PS.: The file /etc/httpd/conf.d/httpd-vhosts.conf is being included because if I insert the following line

```
Alias /pazzanicastanhas /var/www/html/pazzanicastanhas.com.br
```

it works just fine by accessing it with the Public DNS provided by amazon with a /pazzanicastanhas at the end, which in this case would be

http://ec2-54-207-88-168.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com/pazzanicastanhas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I notice is that there is no DNS record for `www.pazzanicastanhas.com.br`, but there is for `pazzanicastanhas.com.br`:

```
$ dig +short www.pazzanicastanhas.com.br
$ dig +short pazzanicastanhas.com.br
54.207.88.168
```

And when you try to load pazzanicastanhas.com.br there is a 301 redirect to the www site:

```
$ curl -v -s pazzanicastanhas.com.br
[snip]
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: Apache/2.2.26 (Amazon)
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.28
< X-Pingback: http://www.pazzanicastanhas.com.br/xmlrpc.php
< Location: http://www.pazzanicastanhas.com.br/
```

But since `www` doesn't actually exist this will never work.

So it looks like you need to create an A record for `www.pazzanicastanhas.com.br` that points to your EC2 instance.

Comment: Yep, that was the problem. To fix it I created the entry www.pazzanicastanhas.com.br as an alias to pazzanicastanhas.com.br in Amazon Route 53 and everything is working just fine now.
Also was great to know that the curl can be used to know exactly what is going on when a side is being loaded (redirect or not, etc).